# C# database path

Tags: c#

Tomorrow I'll go to a c# competition. We'll have to use databases and our sources will be tested on a different computer so I can't hardcode my connectionString like this:

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"c:\users\radu\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication12\WindowsFormsApplication12\Database1.mdf");
```

I compiled this code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string mdfPath = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Database1.mdf");
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=" + mdfPath + ";");

        connection.Open();

        String commandString = "SELECT * FROM Conturi";
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandString, connection);
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();


        while(reader.Read())
        {
            MessageBox.Show(reader.GetString(1) + reader.GetString(2));
        }
        reader.Close();


        String commandString1 = "INSERT INTO Conturi (Nume, Parola) VALUES (@name, @pass)";
        SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand(commandString1, connection);
        command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("name", textBox1.Text.ToString());
        command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("pass", textBox2.Text.ToString());
        command1.ExecuteNonQuery();


    }
```

It let me read the data in my database with that first statement but I can't insert data into db. If I hardcode the path the insertion will work.

Comment: You might want to review [Best Practices - Executing Sql Statements](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/.net/3589/ado-net/14261/best-practices-executing-sql-statements) and understand what `using` is and how you should use it here (no pun intended). Also use the app.config or web.config file to persist the connection string (again, see the link).

Comment: The file path to the .mdf file is not a connection string. You haven't asked a question but I am assuming you want to know how to get a connection string which is very google-able.

Comment: My question is why my code doesn't work for inserting.

Comment: I think you need to scan the directories of the machine and look for `.mdf` files. If you find one, then you get the path and thereafter can execute the operations.

Comment: a sql connection string will either be configured to use  "integrated Security" which will use your windows login or you can specify a sql credentials. depending on how the DB security is set up they may or may not enable you to make inserts

Comment: Wrap your code in `try/catch` to be sure there is no error. Retrieve the result of `ExecuteNonQuery` to see how many rows were affected - should be one.

Comment: @Crowcoder The question said that his insert succeeds depending on the connection string.  So the problem is not with the insert command but rather with the connection string.

Comment: @Crowcoder  "If I hardcode the path the insertion will work."

Comment: Crowcoder is right. Selection succeded but not the insertion. There is no error message.

Comment: @DaniDev so there should be an exception

Comment: @DaniDev  yes it would but using that mdfPath it doesn't. I printed mdfPath and it looks good.

Comment: mdf Path is not a connection string. Look at your connection string that begins `Data Source=...` . Does that look like a file path? In the competition they will have to give you a connection string if you use their database. Typically you pull it from the application configuration file.

Comment: selection vs. insertion can depends on the connection type/ which is determine by the credentials.

Comment: Please familiarize with:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection(v=vs.110).aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: If you are using LocalDB maybe this can help you?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29943900/localdb-mdf-file-property-copy-if-newer-not-working