# Local database inserts not being saved (Entity Framework)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, localdb

I can't save new records to my local database which is attached to the project folder. Data access technology is Entity Framework (c#).

This is in the properties of my local db:

Copy to Output Folder: Copy if newer

Build Acton: Never

It seems that every time my local db has been overwritten with the empty one but I don't know how to solve this.

Many thanks!

Comment: Are you certain that your inserts are actually working if so it sounds like your localdb (sql Express lightweight)  configuration is somehow screwed up or maybe you have a free demo version?

Comment: See if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29943900/localdb-mdf-file-property-copy-if-newer-not-working) is your issue (project folder versus bin folder).

Comment: I solved this. What was my bizarre mistake? I set the parameter "Copy if newer" on datasource in the solution explorer. Instead of that "Copy if newer" should be set up on the .mdf file in the solution explorer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would post this as a comment if i could but i do not have enough reputation to do so.

When inserting records into the database you have to make sure to call the `SaveChanges()` method on the context class. If you don't the data will not be persisted in the database.

Could you post some code that you are using so we can more easily spot what's wrong?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I wrote a comment above explaining what was the mistake.
 
I set the parameter "Copy if newer" for datasource in the solution explorer. Instead of for .mdf file.